# Write an windows app for USB Drive

Tags: portable-applications

I want to write an application in .Net that has to be shipped with USB drive by the manufacturer. Rightnow application targetted to run only in windows. But will have to support other opeating system in future. Is that app needs to be shipped as portable application? What is required in order to run a .net app as portable app in USB drive? If .Net is not a good option, what are other platform that helps to implement this?

Comment: It really depends on what the app does. C# is kind-of portable as far as I know (Windows & Linux at least). C++ although has big support for cross-platform - for example check the boost library which will allow you to do many things in a portable way. And... portable app for USB - remember you cannot use any storage device other than the USB so if the app runs on Windows, do not rely on the registry - use local files instead (again, stored at the USB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do deploy .net applications without .net you have to use tools like Xenocode: http://www.xenocode.com

To run it on others platforms, have a look at the Mono Project: http://www.mono-project.com

Comment: Is there tool like Xenocode needs to be installed in order to run Mono application?

Comment: I don't know. But they have the technology since they use it in MonoTouch. You can try to ask in their forums.